# Using multiple mixin's in one include in sass

Tags: sass, mixins

Can multiple Mixin's be passed into an include in sass.

example

```
@mixin something{
//css declarations
}
@mixin somethingElse{
//css declarations
}
```

Can I do the following

```
.class{
@include something,somethingElse;
}
```

or does it have to be

```
.class{
@include something;
@include somethingElse;

}
```

Comment: cimmanon, yeah I tried it, but it didn't work. I was hoping that it was possible, and that I had my syntax wrong.

Comment: You must use a mix in which will contain other mix ins
[There is more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67297049/13349770)

Answer (score -2):

Each mixin invocation requires an `@include` when using the scss syntax.  If you were using the sass syntax instead, then you could save some keystrokes:

```
=something
    //css declarations

=somethingElse
    //css declarations

.class
    +something
    +somethingElse
```